# What is the task of obtainMessage(int what, int arg1, int arg2) method in handler

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner and trying to understand BluetoothChat source code.In BluetoothChatService i am facing some problem to understand.

```
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
mState = STATE_NONE;

private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
    mState = state;

// Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
```

}
When i allow my bluetooth to turn on then in logcat it shows `"setState() 0 -> 1"`.But i cannot understand how state becomes "1"?

In android official website i found that obtainMessage is a method and it consists of 3 arguments like - `obtainMessage(int what, int arg1, int arg2)`
Can anyone please explain how this obtainMessage works?

JavaExperts need your help to understand the above lines.

Comment: Is this an Android API? If so, please tag accordingly.

Comment: Sorry,now it is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding:
for example u have  a handler in your [main thread](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads)

```
Handler uiHandler;
```

and inside  onCreate(BundlesavedInstanceState) u have

```
    uiHandler=new Handler(){
       public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        super.handleMessage(msg);
               }  
       }
```

we know that ui thread or application's main thread
has intrinsic mechanism of [Looper.prepare() and Looper.loop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper?hl=nb#getMainLooper())

which we don't have to do as we do for other threads 
and we do have an another class with a worker thread(user
 defined thread)

```
     public class MyThread {
           Thread thread=new Thread(new 
         Runnable(){
                @Override
                    public void run(){
                 Message 
               message=uiHandler.obtainMessage(); 
                     ///
                       ///
                      uiHandler.sendMessage(message);         
                     }  
                    }).start();
             }
```

In the above code the purpose of uiHandler.obtainMessage()
is that we know that ui thread is associated with 
a message queue.To send a message to that message queue 
we need an address of a cell in that message queue.

```
          uiHandler.obtainMessage();/*takes an  
       address of that cell(Message object) and
    gives that to message.*/
```

Finally

```
       uiHandler.sendMessage(message) /*sends the 
       message to message queue.*/
```

try to correlate your query with this and do visit
[this website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#getData())
Hope this helps